# Can I create a filter for all paramters in a model without having to write each one in the queryset?

Tags: python, filter, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets

I have a model like this:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    """Class to represent an item..."""

    label = models.TextField(null=True)

    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='item_images/%Y/%m/%d/')

    name = models.TextField()
    #...
    # This has around 20-30 paramters
```

And I have found that I can filter the results as follows:

```py
class ItemViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet): # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
    """API Endpoint to return the list of items"""
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        """ 
            This method allows to filter the results to a set of paramters
        """
        queryset = super(ItemViewset, self).get_queryset()

        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)
        if name is not None:
             queryset = queryset.filter(name__contains=name)        
        label = self.request.query_params.get('label', None)
        if label is not None:
             queryset = queryset.filter(label__contains=label)
        # ... the same for each paramter
        return queryset
```

Is it possible to have this automatically done for each field in the model without having to write the same lines over an over in this view?